# Axios POST imminently without waiting for the server's response

Tags: javascript, for-loop, post, axios, event-loop

Please read carefully this isn't as obvious as it may first sound. I am **not** trying to "pause" the for loop while I wait for the server's response. I am simply wanting the `POST` imminently **without** waiting for the server's response.

I have a `for` loop that loops `N` amount of times and I have a `POST` request inside the `for` loop. I would like `axios` to make the `POST` request then continue the loop **without** waiting for the server's reply. Like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    console.log('Before POST attempt');
    axios({
        url: '/api/fooBar',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            foo: bar
        }
    });

    console.log('After POST attempt');
    //Processes data that takes ~1 seconds before the next loop
}
console.log('After for loop ended');
```

This is the output I am trying to achieve:

```
Before POST attempt
#Server receives POST request and is logged
//Processes data that takes ~1 seconds before the next loop
After POST attempt

Before POST attempt
#Server receives POST request and is logged
//Processes data that takes ~1 seconds before the next loop
After POST attempt

Before POST attempt
#Server receives POST request and is logged
//Processes data that takes ~1 seconds before the next loop
After POST attempt


etc...

After for loop ended
```

In other words, I want the `POST` request to be made immediately during the current loop's iteration.

However, this is what is currently happening (no matter if the for loop loops `3` times or `30`):

```
Before POST attempt
After POST attempt

Before POST attempt
After POST attempt

Before POST attempt
After POST attempt


etc...

After for loop ended

#Server receives POST request and is logged
#Server receives POST request and is logged
#Server receives POST request and is logged

etc...
```

Why?? This is even a localhost server where there is very little latency.

Comment: because axios, like all AJAX is **asynchronous** - that's what the first A in AJAX stands for - you'll want to add the promises returned by axios into a array, then use Promise.all

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand that the POST request would appear to be made after the for loop due to the for loop iterating very fast. However, the for loop I have currently takes several seconds to process other non-related data before it iterates again. I don't think because Axios is asnycours that it needs to wait until the for loop has completed in order to post. Is this what you're saying?

Comment: Watch this for some details on asynchronous behavior. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ.

Comment: Tl;dr: your code in the loop will still execute before the Ajax callback is. Even if your code in the loop is long and the roundtrip to the server is short.

Comment: The short answer is with `es6 promises` (or even just jQuery's `when()`) and callback functions. & Maybe by using a setTimeout rather than a for loop to iterate... Hopefully, someone will be able to give you a more complete answer below.

Comment: `I don't think because Axios is asnycours that it needs to wait until the for loop has completed in order to post. Is this what you're saying?` - read up on the javascript event loop

Comment: I see. I just don't understand why it can't just POST now? I'm not asking it to wait for a response I just want it to run a task.. So it's impossible to POST inside of a for loop?

Comment: `why it can't just POST now` because your loop is doing something for "several seconds" - it's not the loop, it's whatever code you haven't shown inside the loop that means the POST can't happen until that code is completed

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is crazy I don't understand why it can do some tasks but not a POST requests. I thought I liked JS, guess not xD

Comment: perhaps you need to re-think code that takes "several seconds"  - that's an eternity in javascript